# Issues with text / links within <div>

Tags: html, text, tags, hyperlink

I've been looking around and can't seem to find anyone with the same issue on here.

I'm rather new to CSS3, and I'm not sure what's up, but the text and links aren't working and you can't highlight the text. Here's the example:
http://503rephotography.com/_temp/test1.html

And I'm in the process of doing the rest correctly - right now there are a lot of workarounds using old HTML to position images, etc., so I'll fix all of that later! :)

If anyone has any ideas or tips, I would greatly appreciate any insight. Thanks in advance!

Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index is keeping the text below other items on your webpage.

If you change the z-index, for example, of your menu in main.css to 1 you should be able to highlight and click the links.

```
div.menu 
{
font-family: CapsuulaRegular;
color:#fff;
line-height:54px;
width:22%;
height:100%;
padding:0px;
border:none;
border:0;
margin:0px;
background: transparent url('55.png');
font-size: 2.25em;
style=display:block;
position:fixed;
left:70px;
top:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!! I knew it had to be something rather simple...I need to study up on CSS a little more, but thanks a ton for the quick help, you rule!